# "bracelet type" Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, necklace-and-bracelets

[image: question]

This question seems ok but I'm having real difficultly working out the answer using the method they provided. It's so hard to keep track of all the options. Does anyone know of a better more algebraic method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things can be done to a bracelet without changing it: rotating it and flipping it upside down. We want to calculate the number of possible bracelets without counting two bracelets that are identical up to rotation and flipping twice.

First, it is always possible to rotate the bracelet so that the yellow bead will be on top. It is left to determine the color of the 6 other beads, out of which 2 are red and four green.

Let's name the beads (clockwise) by 1-2-3-4-5-6.
Note that 1-6, 2-5 and 3-4 are the symmetric bids (so when flipping the bracelet, the bids in 1-6 change places, 2-5 and 3-4).

In total, there are ${6 \choose 2}$ options to choose the red beads. Out of which, in 3 options, the red beads are in symmetric places.

In the rest ${6 \choose 2}-3$ options, each bracelet is counted twice due to this symmetry. Hence, divide by $2$ and the final answer is:

$$3+\tfrac{{6 \choose 2}-3}{2}=9$$

We can also list the options. If there is a red bead in place #1, the other red can be in any of the places, so there are 5 options.
If there is a red bead in place #2, the other red can be only in places 3-5, because if it was in 6, it would be symmetric to the previous case with a bid at 1 and 5. So in total there are 3 options here.
If there is a red bead in place #3, the only other place for the other red is #4, because other places were already taken into account in previous options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hope I can understand the algebraic method:
Whats a bid?
How did you know there are 3 options where the red beads are symmetric? And where did the 3 in your equation come from?

Comment: A bid is a bead with a typo :)
The 3 symmetric options are 1-6, 2-5, and 3-4. When you flip the bracelet in any of this options, the red bid location (distance clockwise from the yellow) does not change.

Comment: What if the red beads are BOTH in one of the symmetric positions (eg 1-6), also where did the *front 3 in your equation come from?

Comment: If the red bids are in positions 1-6, we need to count them once. This is the 3+. If they are in other positions 1-5 (e.g) then it is identical to 2-6, and we need to count only one of these two combinations.

Comment: Ahh I see. However, I count 4 times where red can be symmetric: 6-4,1-4,5-4 and 2-4. (Yes I know it should be 3 - whats my flaw?)

Comment: The symmetric ones are 1-6, 2-5, 3-4. You counted the not symmetric. So you have 1-2 (=5-6), 1-3 (=4-6), 1-4 (=3-6), 1-5 (=2-6), 2-3 (=4-5), 2-4 (=5-3).

Comment: I see. But why do you start off with the 3 symmetric and take away the three symmetric as well? And also you choose to work with red cus that's easier than green right?

Comment: Choosing locations for red or green is the same. Less red so it's a bit nicer.
You choose two locations for red. Some of chosen couples represent the same thing (these are nonsymmetric couples) and some not. I need to know how many of each type I have and then conclude how many bracelet each represents.

Comment: I understand your working out now thank you. Green and Yellow are determined by red so you don't need to worry about them at all in this approach right?

Comment: Yes. Green is determined by red, and yellow is unique so it is the baseline for everything.